# How to plot Fitted values, observed values and confidence interval and prediction intervals in one plot

Tags: r, linear-regression

I've been tasked with plotting the plot explained in the title here's my code so far:

```
model<-lm(y~.,data=data)
pred <- prediction(model,data=data,interval = 'confidence')
lwr<-pred[76:150]
upr<-pred[151:225]
interval<-cbind(lwr,upr)
```

I'm not sure where to go after this because I can't figure out how plot the interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `ggplot2`

```
library(tidyverse)

data(mtcars)


mylm <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)
summary(mylm)

myc <- predict(mylm, newdata = mtcars$wt, interval = "confidence")

fit <- myc[,1]
low <- myc[,2]
high <- myc[,3]


myp <- predict(mylm, newdata = mtcars, interval = "predict")



mtcars %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = wt, y = fit), color = "green") +
  geom_line(aes(x = wt, y = fit), color = "green") +
  geom_point(aes(x = wt, y = low), color = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(x = wt, y = low), color = "red") +
  geom_point(aes(x = wt, y = high), color = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(x = wt, y = high), color = "red") +
  geom_point(aes(x = wt, y = myp[,1]), color = "blue") +
  geom_line(aes(x = wt, y = myp[,1]), color = "blue") +
  geom_point(aes(x = wt, y = myp[,2]), color = "darksalmon") +
  geom_line(aes(x = wt, y = myp[,2]), color = "darksalmon") +
  geom_point(aes(x = wt, y = myp[,3]), color = "darksalmon") +
  geom_line(aes(x = wt, y = myp[,3]), color = "darksalmon")
```

[image]

Fitted are the blue, the confidence is the red, and the prediction the dark salmon, observed are the black.

By the way I know you can place wt and mpg into the `ggplot()` and have it affect all geom's but I just prefer to do it this way.

Comment: Thanks so much!! This is exactly what I needed.